# Splitting and storing input in a variable in Apache spark using java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have two files as input , First file will be having role number and subject1 mark and second file will have role number and subject2 mark, First file will be coming in spark streaming and second file will be in my hdfs, How i can split the file like key, value pair and  extract the value and store it in a variable using java in spark, I tried but having difficulty in extracting and storing as integer in a variable using javapairrdd. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
JavaRDD<String> sub1MarksRDD = sc.textFile("/user/ubuntu/sub1Marks.dat");
List<String> ccList = new ArrayList<String>();
ccList = sub1MarksRDD.collect();

JavaRDD<String> sub2MarksRDD = sc.textFile("/user/ubuntu/sub2marks.dat");

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> result = sub1MarksRDD.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<String,String,Integer>() {

                public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String w) {
                      return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(w, 1);
                }
            }
    );
```

How should we go ahead to create a pair rdd to map the role no,marks1 from sub1Marks.dat with the data in sub2Marks.dat. How to extract the marks fields based on the role no and store it to a variable.

Comment: Please add your code so far and explain the issue. As it stands, I really have no idea what you're asking.